# Prompt gamma emission vs gamma decay

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, gamma-rays

I understand prompt gamma emission to mean gamma emission in a time period shorter than a second. I understand gamma decay to be the relaxion of a nucleus into a lower energy level by emission of a gamma.

I see the term "prompt gamma emission" in one form or another a lot. My question is whether there is any difference in the physical process behind these two things? Is the only difference the time period in which they take place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's "prompt" depends on just what you're doing.  One second is a brief time interval if you're interested in radiological shielding, but an eternity if you're interested in the spectroscopy of a single nucleus.

For instance, suppose you have neutrons capturing on some material.  The neutrons typically capture in some very excited nuclear orbital and release a "cascade" of gamma rays with total energy of about 8 MeV.  But in general adding a neutron to a stable isotope makes it unstable against beta decay, and in general beta decays *also* proceed through some excited state and are accompanied by a cascade of gamma rays.  The difference is that electromagnetism is fast, with typical lifetimes of femto- and pico-seconds, while the weak interaction is slow, with lifetimes of seconds, hours, or years.

While your neutron source is on, you'll see both neutron-capture gamma cascades and beta-delayed gamma rays; while the neutron source is off, you'll see only the delayed gammas.

I do some work at a cold pulsed neutron source where the neutrons take about a half-millisecond to come to thermal equilibrium before getting sent to my experiment, where they arrive in twenty-millisecond "bunches."  When I talk to people there, radiological responses faster than the half-millisecond are "prompt", since we can't distinguish those from fluctuations in the neutron beam, while responses of a second are "glacial," spread over dozens of neutron pulses.

I have also done work at charged-particle accelerators, where the beam has structure at sub-microsecond timescales.  There a half-millisecond is a long time.

So, it depends on what you're doing.  When in doubt, context.